# Where is the source of this Midrash/Agadita in the Ein Yaakov

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash

I saw in the **[הקדמת הכותב](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47606&st=&pgnum=10)** of the [Ein Yaakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Yaakov) the following midrash/agadita cited:

> בן זומה אומר מצינו פסוק כולל יותר והוא שמע ישראל וגו׳ בן ננס אומר 
>    מצינו פסוק כולל יותר והוא ואהבת לרעך כמוך שמעון בן פזי אומר מצינו פסוק כולל
>   יותר והוא את הכבש אחד תעשה בבקר וגו׳ עמד ר׳ פלוני על רגליו ואמר הלכה כבן
>    פזי דכתיב ככל אשר אני מראה אותך את תבנית המשכן וגו׳
>
> *Ben Zoma says we find the most important verse is  (Deut. 6:4) "Hear, Oh Israel etc", Ben Nanas says we find the most important verse is (Lev. 19:18) "And you shall love your fellow like yourself," Shimon Ben Pazi says we find the most important verse is (Ex. 29:39) "One lamb you shall sacrifice in the morning and the second lamb in the late afternoon"; Rabbi Ploni stood up and said "The Halacha is like (Shimon) Ben Pazi for it says (Ex. 25:9) "Exactly like that which I had shown you regarding the image of the Mishkan etc."*

Does anyone know where the source of this Midrash is? I looked in other editions of the Ein Yaakov and have not seen it sourced anywhere

Comment: The source is probably no longer extant, but it's hard to prove such a thing.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up at least two pages saying that they can't find it. CC @magicker72